# Using keypress to click an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To scroll through content on my Laravel-based web app, there are arrows (anchor tags) on the left and right side of the screen.

**Code**

```
<a href="/" id="ContentLeft"><span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span></a>

<a href="/" id="ContentRight"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fgzc1pa/)

**Question**:
I would like to click those anchors by pressing the left and right arrow key on the keyboard (keycode 37 and 39)

**Internet search results**:
I found a piece of code for a text box and button combination that may be close to the solution, however, this does not work as there is no textbox, only an anchor tag.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#TextBoxId').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==37)
      $('#buttonId').click();
    });
});
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So? what is the problem?

Comment: Not a fan of triggering `click` events. Post the library you're using to scroll through the pages. There must an API to do this without triggering events.

Comment: I am not using a particular library to scroll through the pages. The view is passed a link for the content 'to the left' and a link for the content 'to the right', and these are put in the anchor tags. All I want is to activate those anchors when the arrow keys are pressed.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle then, please?

Comment: Added to the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the use of [`.which`](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) over `.keyCode` when jQuery is used.

Then I can't tell why it doesn't work with `keypress`... But it works fine with `keyup`.

You have to have an element to bind the event. So you can bind it to the whole document if you wish...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which==37){
      $('.fa-angle-left').click();
    }
    if(e.which==39){
      $('.fa-angle-right').click();
    }
  });
  
  // Just to console.log something here...
  $(".fa-angle-left").on("click",function(){
    console.log("Left clicked.");
  });
  $(".fa-angle-right").on("click",function(){
    console.log("Right clicked.");
  });
});
```

```css
.arrow-leftright {
  color: dimgray;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 70vh; 
  width: 25vw; 
  font-size: 60px; 
  line-height: 70vh; 
}

.arrow-leftright:focus, .arrow-leftright:hover {
  color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" id="leftPicture" class="arrow-leftright" style="left: 0; text-align: left;"><span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span></a>

<a href="#" id="rightPicture" class="arrow-leftright" style="right: 0; text-align: right;"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! How would this work without the `#TextBoxId` part? Since there is no text box ;)

Comment: Excellent. The working solution is: 
    <script>
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        if(e.which==37){
          $('.fa-angle-left').click();
        }
        if(e.which==39){
          $('.fa-angle-right').click();
        }
      });
    </script>
If you edit your answer I will award it to you.

Comment: Isn't it what I actually have? Within `$(document).ready()`, `$(this)` is the document.